# SQL select int update on same table without ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I had table t1 with 4 columns.

```
A B C D 
--------
1 A 1 10
1 A 1 15
1 A 2 12
1 A 3 11
```

I need update, that take the max value from column D based on grouped columns A, B and C. And then update D column for every row with the same A,B,C with that max value.

So, for first row, D will be updated to 15. For third and fourth stay the same value, because A, B and C are not the same.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canonical way to do this using standard SQL is:

```
update t
    set d = (select max(t2.d) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c);
```

Many specific databases support alternative solutions that are likely to have better performance.

Comment: Thx. Solved. I try this solution before, but problem was in that one column was nullable and i get ora error. So i try to concate and coalesce the nullable. In finalle, it looks like

update t
    set d = (select max(t2.d) from t t2 where t2.a||coalesce(t2.b,'')||t2.c = t.a||coalesce(t.b,'')||t.c);

Its super slow, but I do this after first table data insert. I can make helping column with this concated values and then easy compare..

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following statements :

```
update tab
  set D = (select max(D) from tab)
 where (A, B, C) in 
(
select A, B, C
  from tab t
 group by A, B, C
 having count(1)>1   
);
select * from tab;
    A   B   C   D
    -   -   -   --
    1   A   1   15
    1   A   1   15
    1   A   2   12
    1   A   3   11
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/NVGFT19737)